# PlayerScore prefab in unity gives value in gameover screen as 0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a 3d game, in it there are two scenes, one is game scene and the other is GameOver scene. In the game scene the score is counted live as the player moves along the z axis using the following code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform player;
    public Text ScoreValue; //means, input is required, since a variable has been created

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        ScoreValue.text = ((player.position.z-15)/10).ToString("0"); //ToString("0") is to remove all decimal points
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("CurrentScore", ((player.position.z-15)/10).ToString("0"));
    }
}
```

Since this is on the Game Level scene, the score is calculated according to player movement by dragging the player object into the script. 
When game ends, the scene transiitions to the GameOver screen using SceneManagement. 
Since I want to display the score from Game Level in the Game over scene, I use a prefab to store the score.

Now in the Gameover scene I have a text object which I wanted to be updated with the final value of score form the Game Level, so i made a script for it which is as follows:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameOverScore : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text OverScore;

    void Update()
    {  

        OverScore.text = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("CurrentScore").ToString();      

    }
}
```

Here, you have to drag the text(score value) which you want to keep updating whenever the level ends.
The default score value in game over scene is set to: -
Using this, the score text in Game Over scene should get updated  to the final score of the game scene. 
But, whenever the game ends and there is a transition to the Game Over scene, the score in Game Over scene changes from: '-', to: 0.
But when the level ended, the score was not 0, can someone tell me what to do or what code to use so that the value in Game Over scene is updated to final value of Game Level scene? I would really appreciate if you could help me out.

Comment: You are setting `string` and getting `float`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting a PlayerPrefs value as string in script one
Your next script you're trying to get a PlayerPrefs as a Float. Unity stores these values seperately, even if you call them by the same name.

`OverScore.text = PlayerPrefs.GetString("CurrentScore")`

Also Read: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.GetString.html

Comment: Thank You :-)But now I have a whole another problem, i have tried setting up a High Score system but the highscore does not update if player scores more than the previous high score, I have posted it as another thread :-/